# Visual Studio Code: How to detect dead typescript code?

Tags: typescript, unused-variables

There are tslint rules available for private method. But How can I find out if the public method is not used anywhere in the project and hence candidate for the dead code. I am using Visual studio code for Typescript.

Comment: I doubt you will find a TSLint rule that can do this, as TSLint processes the files individually. To write a rule that deals with multiple files, it's necessary to analyse the compiled program in a different manner. Private methods can only reside in the one file, that's why those are easily checked.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look to https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-unused-exports

It produces an output like this

```
$ ts-unused-exports tsconfig.json

4 modules with unused exports

src/lambda: handler
src/routes/crud: default
```

Comment: The question is about unused code, not just unused exports.

Comment: By detecting unused exports you can find dead code. But if you have a solution, please, share

Comment: He is asking for detection of unused public functions. What if you have an angular component? You can have an unexported public function that gets called from the html-template. Its not exported, yet still in use. Exports only wont do it.

Comment: Also try `ts-prune` package which does the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and [dpdm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dpdm) was the best found solution. But I wanted one integrated in Visual Code so in the end was created an extension named [Find unused exports](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iulian-radu-at.find-unused-exports). It allows to easily see and go to unused exports in a js/ts project.

Answer (score 1):

It's a quite complex issue with VSCode for now. Suggest you switch to WebStorm https://dev.to/mokkapps/why-i-switched-from-visual-studio-code-to-jetbrains-webstorm-939

There is a lot of complaint about it on this thread https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29293 but unfortunately it never gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think you can do that for all your code, but you can open the context menu over a method/function/property, and then select 'find all references'. If none is found, you can mark it as a candidate for deletion.

Of course this method is not perfect. For example, you could call a method from an object which is an instance of a class but has been cast to `any` previously, but it's a starting point.